# What is the lifecycle of this ClojureScript REPL?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to understand the lifecycle of ClojureScript and its evaluation in repl.

As I understand when I start a repl with the following command `lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-listen` and then when I listen using the following `(repl/connect "http://localhost:9000/repl")` -

1. It creates a TCP server which listens on port 9000.
2. The browser establishes some sort of polling, where it is polling for any changes.
3. When I execute any code in the repl this changes the compiled `*.js` file.
4. This *.js file is then served to the browser.
5. The browser replaces its current *.js file with the new one.
6. Hence the changes due to the code executed in the repl show up in the browser.

I am trying to verify and understand this better. Will appreciate if anyone can elaborate on this or point me to links that better explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be strict, the execution environment for javascript needn't be a browser, although 'most' uses are.

For a browser based execution environment:

1. HTTP Server created on port 9000
2. Browser connects to server using [HTTP Long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling), establishing an execution environment. (this is a HTTP `GET` to `http://server:9000/repl`)
3. When code is executed in the REPL, the clojurescript is compiled to javascript and the javascript is sent as the 'response' (see below) in the HTTP long poll. (note this is not 'serving' the js file to the browser', rather just the forms that are relevant)
4. The javascript forms are evaluated in the browser.
5. The javascript environment in the browser is now up to date.

The easiest way to follow this is to monitor the http traffic using something like the network monitor in google chrome developer tools.

*Note:* there is endless scope for confusion between request/response in an HTTP long polling setup, this might help:

```
  [REPL]    -> [browser] travels via HTTP Response
  [browser] -> [REPL]    travels via HTTP Request.
```